# Avoid 26 if/elseif/else statements when checking for a letter in user input

Tags: java, if-statement, code-cleanup

I was just wondering if there was a simple way to check for the value of a letter from user input. For example,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String message = scanner.nextLine();
String letter;
int length = message.length();
for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
    letter = message.substring(i, i+1);
    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
        System.out.println("letter a");
        // Of course the real program won't just print out "letter a" but this is
        // to show that all actions are different
    } else if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase("b") {
        System.out.println("letter b");
    } // etc... for all of the possible values of "letter"
}
```

Is there any way to write the above statement without having to make 26+ if/else statements? (I know there's switch-case but you'd still have to write 26+ of them). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, that depends on the "do something" and "do something else", don't it? If you have to do 26 *different* things, then you have 26 pieces of different code, so what is it you think you can eliminate?

Comment: If you show us what your business logic is inside the `if-else` blocks, then maybe we can find a way to streamline things.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the clarification Andreas - say I had to do a different action for every letter (like maybe print out a different string). I'm not exactly sure, I'm just asking if there's a way to make cleaner code than this.

Comment: @dumpong we would need to take a look at a few of those "actions" you speak of. Do you have 26 methods lying around?

Comment: You could initialize a `Map` where the keys are the 26 letters of the alphabet and the values are the messages.  Then just access that `Map` with the user's input.

Comment: @JVemon thankfully not haha. Just a little printing/appending to do.

Comment: As is, you can just remove all the `if` and just do `System.out.println("letter " + letter.toLowerCase());`

Comment: use switch case for characters that will be helpful

Comment: @JB Nizet yes, but I will print out a whole lot of different strings for each letter, not just that letter. I'm trying to make an ascii art text generator btw. When you put it "a" it would spurt out a letter a made out of slashes and underscores and stuff, basically ascii art.

Comment: Then create a Map<String, String> containing the ascii art translation of each letter, and use `System.out.println(translationMap.get(letter.toLowerCase());`.

Comment: @JB Nizet yeah, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen too since he suggested it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the comments you are just printing different text depending on the letter.  In that case, Tim's idea of using a Map is pretty good. I will show you a basic example:

---

In your class, create a `HashMap`. I'm guessing that a `final` `static` one would be fine:

```
private static final HashMap<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    messages.put("A", "Hello!");
    messages.put("B", "Again!");
    messages.put("C", "Etc etc!");
}
```

Notice how the keys are all uppercase. So when you get the letter you should convert it to uppercase too:

```
letter = message.substring(i,i+1).toUpperCase();
```

So now you can get the message to print doing this:

```
String toPrint = messages.get(letter);
```

And you can just print that without making 26 switches.

---

The above solution assumes you need to print some sort of customized text. Otherwise the others' solutions are fine: just print the letter.

Comment: Thanks very much. It also fixes a little formatting issue I had earlier that I hadn't mentioned. 100%. +1

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you want to do in the if parts, this is the most generic approach to this problem:

```
    final Map<String, Consumer<String>> actions = new HashMap<>();
    actions.put("a", this::performActionA);
    actions.put("b", this::performActionB);

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String message = scanner.nextLine();
    String letter;
    final int length = message.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        letter = message.substring(i, i + 1);
        actions.get(letter).accept(message);
    }
```

And then you need to have the methods like this:

```
private void performActionA(final String message) {
    System.out.println("Test.performActionA()");
}

private void performActionB(final String message) {
    System.out.println("Test.performActionB()");
}
```

Of course in production you might want to check if there even is an action, but I leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the letter into char value and then directly check for the ASCII equivalent. Then it will be numerical and easier too. This way whatever be your operations convert it into ASCII format and it will be done easily.

Comment: sorry if I'm being a newbie here but how would one accomplish that?

Comment: @dumpong I would need a little more detail than that about your program coz all you are doing in the snippet code above is print each letter of the string and nothing else.